# Having trouble getting passport.js working. Unable to get the user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

In my mongodb, there is clearly a User with username "testuser", but I am still getting "failed to login!" when I enter this in. Note: Not using the password yet. Just trying to make sure I can check that the entered username exists first.

navbar-login.jade

```
.navbar-right(ng-controller="mvNavBarLoginCtrl")
    form.navbar-form 
        .form-group
            input.form-control(placeholder="email", ng-model="username")
        .form-group
            input.form-control(type="password", placeholder="password", ng-model="password")
        button.btn.btn-primary(ng-click="signin(username, password)") Sign In
```

mvNavBarLoginCtrl.js (I keep getting "failed to login!", which means {success:false}, which I believe means the user wasn't found)

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvNavBarLoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {             
    $scope.signin = function(username, password) {
        $http.post('/login', {username:username, password:password}).then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.success) {
                console.log("logged in!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("failed to login!");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

routes.js (I get the "no user found.")

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
        if(err) {return next(err);}
        if(!user) {
            console.log("no user found.");
            res.send( {success:false} );
        }

        // we are using XHR and not a form to login so we gotta do this
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if(err) {return next(err);}
            res.send( {success:true, user:user} ); 
        })
    })

    auth(req, res, next); 
})
```

server.js

```
var User = mongoose.model('User'); 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne( {'username': username} ).exec(function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user); 
            }
            else {
                return done(null, false); 
            }
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    if(user) {
        done(null, user._id); 
    }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne( {_id: id} ).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(user) {
            return done(null, user); 
        }
        else {
            return done(null, false); 
        }
    })
});
```

express.js config (not sure if I did this right with Express 4)

```
app.set('views', config.rootPath+ '/server/views'); 
app.set('view engine', 'jade'); 

app.use(morgan('dev')); 

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); 
app.use(session({secret: '<mysecret>', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));

app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session()); 

app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
        src: __dirname + '/public', 
        compile: compile
    }
));
app.use(express.static(config.rootPath + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1):

passport.use(new LocalStrategy...) was not being called.

This has to do with the new Express 4 config. I needed to add bodyParser.json() to express.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I was unable to find any documentation for this. All of the passport.js documentation seems to be outdated and intended for Express 3 which only requires an app.use(express.bodyParser());. The middleware config is the culprit if anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your passport.js file if the username is undefined or not? Just console.log that.

And if it shows that it is not undefined, check your mongodb database to see if anything is actually saved in there. Grab robomongo to check this. http://robomongo.org/

```
var User = mongoose.model('User'); 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        /*Check if these values exist, if they do something is wrong in mongodb*/
        console.log('THIS IS THE USERNAME', username);
        console.log('THIS IS THE PASSWORD', password);
        User.findOne( {'username': username} ).exec(function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user); 
            }
            else {
                return done(null, false); 
            }
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    if(user) {
        done(null, user._id); 
    }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne( {_id: id} ).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(user) {
            return done(null, user); 
        }
        else {
            return done(null, false); 
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: It seems like passport.use(...) isn't doing anything. I don't see those console.logs you told me to include at all. If I do a console.log right before passport.use(...), I can see that.

Comment: hmmmm okay.... so passport.use() isn't being called...

Did robomonogo show that the user exists?

Comment: Yes, the user exists.